# how to fix moodle installation Dataroot security error

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle 2 on a localhost server and I'm having trouble making the moodledata directory secure

error msg say

```
Dataroot location is not secure
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dataroot folder has to be outside the web folder.

So if you have something like `/var/www/yourmoodlesite`

Then dataroot should something like `/var/sitedata`